# Flutter app: how about changing the state inside 'build'?

Tags: flutter, stateful

I am new to Flutter.

I need to change state in the method 'build'. I am wandering if I need to do it with setState.
Also can I initiate navigation in build?
On one hand, setState will signal that the component should rebuild. As I am already building it, and building it in a right way, do I need to initiate another rebuilding? If yes, should I exit the method 'build' right after invoking setState?

Comment: Thanks for submitting this question.  I had it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The premise is false: You shouldn't change the state inside `build`.

There are clear life-cycles that should be used to do these state changes. Depending on what change accured, you may want to use:

- didChangeDependencies, for changes related to InheritedWidgets
- didUpdateWidget, when the created of this widget rebuilt it with new variables

You should use these over `build` to do custom work instead.

Answer (score 0):

State changes and navigation should be performed before build: either in initState or in event handlers.